# FCM Android: Prevent expanding notification when pushed from REST API with an image

Tags: android, rest, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the FCM legacy REST API to send notifications to my Android App. I've managed to include a *LargeIcon* in the notification using the *image* attribute. My problem is that I don't want my notification to expand, as when it expands it shows this image enlarged, covering the whole expanded notification. 
When the notification collapses it displays the icon properly to the right.

How can I prevent the notification from expanding when pushing from the REST API (while App is in background).

Here's my notification body:

```
{
    title: 'Title',
    body: 'Notification Body',
    icon: 'myicon',
    image: 'url_of_image'
};
```

EDIT:
As requested I've added a screenshot of how the notifications look.
Also, the Debug Stacktrace shows that the system downloads the image from the given url when the notification is received.
[image]

Comment: The legacy APi doesn't support the image attribute. Can you show us the URL you are using to send the notification?

Comment: I'm pushing to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: That URL is for the legacy API. The new HTTP V1 API will look something like this - https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send

Comment: Refer this document to migrate to the new API - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Comment: I'm very curious as to how the image is getting rendered for you, considering that the legacy API doesn't have an image parameter as you can see here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref. Are you rendering it from your app?

Comment: Great. I'll see fit to migrate. No, I've tested with Data + Notification Messages while App is in the background. I'll post a pic asap, as the image does in fact, go through

Comment: Yes! Please do! I'd like to know how that works. Also, if you just setting up push notifications for your app, I'd suggest to do it with the new API instead of the legacy for multiple reasons mentioned in the about FCM documentation

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the notification. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a data-only push notification to your device. Send the image URL as part of the data payload.

This will give you control in the onMessageReceived method. Here you can generate and display the notification however you like it. Retrieve the image URL here and download the image and create a notification with the image as the icon or however you want it to be rendered.

Comment: Yes, I've found this approach. May I note, I need to also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082939/9489014) implementation of FCM Service, in order to guarantee that the notification gets through even when the app is killed.